# unable to delete sharepoint home library

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

I'm trying to delete the home library as it is not needed anymore. Unfortunately, there isn't a 'delete library' option under the permissions section. Does anyone know how to delete this library? I have tried the following (see screenshot):[image]

Hopefully, I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see below your updated PowerShell code to delete library

> SharePoint On-premises

```
$web = Get-SPweb "Site Url"
$list = $web.Lists["Documents"]
$list.AllowDeletion =$true
$list.Update() 
$list.Delete()
```

> Office 365

```
$SiteUrl = "Site Url"
$Cred = Get-Credential
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
$ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$list=$ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents")
$ctx.Load($list)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$list.AllowDeletion = $true
$list.Update()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$list.DeleteObject()
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

**Note:** For Office 365 you need SharePoint Online Management Shell install on your machine. That you can download from below link

[SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35588)

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using SharePoint Online.

In this case, you can use the PnP PowerShell to interact with SPO and perform operations.

Simply install the module as below:

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
```

After that, you can delete the list as below:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "<https://site-collection-url>"
Remove-PnPList -Identity Documents -Force
```

References - [PnP-PowerShell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell)

[Remove-PnPList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnplist?view=sharepoint-ps)